# Cordova 3.3 plugins do not work

Tags: cordova

I have created a project in the following way, but when I run it in iOS simulator none of the plugins work.

```
cordova create myApp com.example.myapp myApp
cd myApp
cordova platform add ios
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.globalization
```

Checking the console for `navigator.notification` for example, returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is a bug that requires you to run

```
cordova build
```

or specify the platform:

```
cordova build ios
```

Before the plugins will work. When you will see the `cordova_plugins.js` file get populated, you will know the plugins were truly added. Do the same after you remove plugins.

Here's a link to the bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5647